# Python - tkinter - How to capture bind function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, return

```
from tkinter import StringVar, messagebox, Entry, Tk

def accept(event):
    acceptInput=messagebox.askquestion("Input Assessment","do you accept this input?")
    return acceptInput

window=Tk()
userInput=StringVar()
e=Entry(window,textvariable=userInput)
e.pack()
e.bind('<Return>',accept)
window.mainloop()
```

My question is: How do I capture the returned value of the accept function?

I've tried:

```
e.bind('<Return>',a=accept.get())
```

and

```
a=e.bind('<Return>',accept).get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bound functions don't "return". Your callback needs to set a global variable or call some other function. For example:

```
def accept(event):
    global acceptInput
    acceptInput=messagebox.askquestion("Input Assessment","do you accept this input?")
```

... or ...

```
def accept(event):
    acceptInput=messagebox.askquestion("Input Assessment", "do you accept this input?")
    do_something(acceptInput)
```

It is up to you to define what you want to do in `do_something` (eg: write the data to disk, show an error, play a song, etc), or how you want to use the global variable in some other function.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, these things are easiest to accomplish if pieces of your application are instances of a class -- Then `accept` can just set an attribute on the class.  In this case, you might want to bind that functionality up in the `Entry`:

```
class AcceptEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<Return>', self.accept)
        self.acceptInput = None

    def accept(self, event):
        self.acceptInput = messagebox.askquestion("Input Assessment",
                                                  "do you accept this input?")
```

Comment: Can you advise a way to do this without the creation of a class please?

Comment: @Robert -- a global or mutable module level variable is really the only other option.

Answer (score 0):

For the function `bind`, the `<Return>` doesn't mean the `return` of a function. Instead, it does mean the event "*Enter key*" that is pressed by the user.

So, if you like to get the response from the `messagebox`, then you have do it with other ways. Possibly using with another `StringVar()` option with your `messagebox`, or using any global variable.